# Angular Forms: Set all fields untouched, not dirty and valid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like a function to set all fields untouched, not dirty and valid on a given form.I need that so i can display errors properly.Here is what i have tried.It does not work for some reason.

```
angular.forEach($scope.LoginForm, function (input) {
            if (input.hasOwnProperty('$viewValue'))
              input.$setPristine();
        });
```

As you can see, a ngmodel on a form alwyas has a property called $viewValue.

I am getting the following error.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly `$scope.LoginForm` has an enumerable property that is undefined (or whose value is `undefined`), so you can test for that:

```
angular.forEach($scope.LoginForm, function (input) {
    if (input && input.hasOwnProperty('$viewValue')) {
      input.$setPristine();
    }
});
```

Maybe you can even test that `input.hasOwnProperty` is a proper function using `typeof input.hasOwnProperty === 'function'` but that may be pushing it a little. Instead, look at what's in the LoginForm object and go from there. Or even better, maybe look in the Angular docs if Angular has a proper way of iterating over form models?

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring example:

```
 angular.forEach(form.$$controls, function (input) {

            if (input.$viewValue === undefined) {
                input.$setPristine();
            }
        });
```